# Backbone: getting the view element that triggered an event

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I have a template like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-small edit"  model-id="<%= model.id %>" href="">
  <i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i>
  edit
</a>
```

And a view defined like this:

```
src.views.WinesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  [...]
  events: {
    'click a.edit': 'edit'
  },

  edit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var a = $(e.target);
    var id = a.attr('model-id');
    app.edit(id);
  },
  [...]
```

if the user clicks on the "edit" text, everything works fine, but if the users clicks on the icon-pencil icon (the content of the  tag) the event is correctly raised, but e.target points to the i tag, and not to the a.

In fact, what I want is that if any tag inside the one I binded to tfires an event, I want that event to be raised and to easily get a reference to the element I binded from backbone...

I could solve it with:

```
edit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(e.target);
  if (a[0].tagName!=='A') { a = a.parent(); }
  var id = a.attr('model-id');
  app.edit(id);
},
```

but I was wondering if there's a better, more elegant and generic way to achieve it...

Comment: `e.currentTarget` inside callback gives you the dom element that **bubbled** the event

Comment: Thanks a lot Deeptechtons, please include it as an aswer so I can mark is at the correct one...

Comment: Please upvote and mark the existing answer by **flyingnude** it works well

Comment: already upvoted your comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [jQuery's $.closest() method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
edit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var a = $(e.currentTarget).closest('a');
  var id = a.attr('model-id');
  app.edit(id);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this way you get the attribute value from your model

```
edit: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = this.model.get("model.id");

  app.edit(id);
},
```

In case you need to get an HTML attribute from the element

```
$(e.currentTarget).attr("title");
```